# Using MvvmCross 5.6 NavigationService with autofac IoC

Tags: xamarin.android, inversion-of-control, mvvmcross

I am undergoing an mvvmcross upgrade from 4.* to 5.6. This is in a Xamarin.Android project.

Autofac is registered as the IoT container and has been since day 1.

During the upgrade I have had to inject IMvxNAvigationService into a bunch of core services. These services are registered in CreateIocProvider in my setup class.

Now at runtime I am receiving the following:

Cannot resolve parameter 'MvvmCross.Core.Navigation.IMvxNavigationService navService' of constructor

How do I ensure that the underlying navigation service is registered in time? I cannot find anything in the docs.

I have tried swapping autofac for the Mvx IoC container which seemed to solve the problem but had to revert as it doesn't support registration of abstract classes.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way around my specific issue.

To resolve I ended up removing Autofac and registering every service/component, including the abstract's individually, using the simple IoC container.